# Call extern C++ method from only strong named C# assembly

Tags: c#, c++, extern, strongname

How can I specify friend assembly in C++ (not Visual).
I have a C++ assembly that contains extern method, which I use in C# strong named assembly. And I want that only my C# method in strong named assembly calls extern C++ method. Do you know how can I do it?